# Email Exchange and Cloudflare

Tags: email, cloudflare

i would like to offer Mail Accounts without giving the real server Adress to the public (I'm using Cloudflare). Currently i use a e-mail-Relay to send messages, the harder problem is to receive e-mails.

So everytime if i add a MX Record my real Server IP is visible to the public. I know that there is as example google apps which can be used as exchange server, the problem is google is complicated and expensive, for that money i could create a further server.

First Question:
Is there a possiblity to use pop3 yust with a a record on the domain and without mx entrys

Second Question:
Does someone know a free exchange server for in and outgoing mail?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You do know that your server IP will likely be littered among the `Received:` SMTP headers, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a possiblity to use pop3 yust with a a record on the domain
> and without mx entrys

If a domain lacks `MX` records, MTAs will fall back to sending mail to the `A` record for the zone. See [RFC 5321](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-5).

You're missing the larger point here, though. POP3 is a mechanism for getting mail from the server to the end recipient. That won't do you any good if servers can't communicate with your server via SMTP, which is the protocol that is use for all inter-server communication.

> Does someone know a free exchange server for in and outgoing mail?

SF doesn't do product recommendations.

Comment: I tried to use the A Records (A mail.domain.com - IP Adress) and removed the MX records, sadly i wasn't able to get a connection to my server trough cloudflare and the port. So could this be a configuration issue on my side?

Comment: Cloudflare is for HTTP/HTTPS traffic. It is not going to work for SMTP or POP3.